# There's a file in my trash that can't be deleted

Tags: files, trash

It says "Could not delete file" every time I try to delete it. It's actually not even a file, but an empty folder. When I have this issue in Windows I usually use a program called Unlocker, but I don't think Linux has anything similar.

Comment: Which "trash" folder are you looking in?

Comment: Trash on the desktop

Comment: Open up the terminal and do `cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files`.  Then do `ls -l` and check ownership of the file you're trying to delete.

Comment: "No such file or directory." There's no Trash in the share folder.

Comment: Then something in your system is hinky.  The trash folder should be in ~/.local/share, but if the Trash folder was erased then that could be a problem.

Comment: Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Though it's a different problem, I wonder if this is similar to [the situation here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42437). Please edit your question to include the output of `mount`, and also to include the output of `ls -al ~/.gvfs` and `ls -ald ~/.gvfs`. If those two `ls` commands don't show any directory called `.gvfs` and nothing with `gvfs` appears in the output of `mount`, try *creating* and chmod'ing the trash folders [as described here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42448); please also include what commands you ran to do that and if it helped or changed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the whole Trash folder. Is it under `~/.local/share/Trash`? Then do:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Comment: There's no Trash folder in there.

Comment: I'm a Kubuntu fan... Well, I would try to find where it is if I were You, and try to delete the whole Trash folder.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start looking. I'm actually running Xubuntu, by the way.

Comment: I mean I would search the Internets.

Comment: @Spectro When was the last time you rebooted?  Have you been tinkering with the system at all?

Comment: I've rebooted many times since I've had this issue. What do you mean by tinkering? I'm a novice Linux user, so the answer is probably no. I haven't messed with anything that I wasn't sure what it would do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, the file in the trash was the dconf folder,the dconf folder was locked to root as the owner, I had to chown it first.

```
sudo chown user ~/.local/share/Trash/files/.cache/dconf
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/.cache/dconf
```

I suppose the rm -rf was unnecessary since just emptying the trash would have worked too after chowning the folder, either way it's gonzo.